# Python - How can I get just the IP from socket.getpeername()?

Tags: python, sockets

I am curious to know how you can return ONLY the IP address of the connected user using

```
ip = socket.getpeername()
```

Because whenever I use that in my server it returns the IP and socket port, I only want the IP, or at least a way to replace the port with Null... I tried using the replace function but that just gives me an error

```
attributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'replace
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the error suggests, `getpeername` returns a tuple. To get the IP you should simply take the first element:

```
ip = socket.getpeername()[0]
```

Comment: In 9 minutes when it let's me I will click accepted answer, this worked fab. Thanks